# Label on Ext.form.combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hello,

Can someone explain to me how can I enter a label in form.combobox to show the name of the ComboBox?

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id             : 'searchCombo',
    displayField   : 'nome',
    tpl            : new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item">',
                        '{nome}',
                        '</div></tpl>'
                    ),
    valueField     : 'id',
    anchor         : '100%',
    queryParam     : 'termo',
    forceSelection : true,
    store          : new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url           : server + 'pessoa/dados/',
        fields        : ['id', 'nome'],
        root          : 'linhas',
        totalProperty : 'total'
    }),
    editable       : true,
    triggerAction  : 'all',
    minChars       : 1,
    loadingText    : 'Loading...',
    width          : 200,
    selectOnFocus  :true,
    stateful       :false,
    listeners      : ....
    }},
}),
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003239/how-to-set-extjs-combobox-label-width/33008314)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below things to add label? Here is [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-fieldLabel)

```
labelStyle: 'width:30px',
fieldLabel: 'Super Long Label That Cuts Off'
```

Comment: @thepeter It does work, as can be seen [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11u5).